# ObjC: Append data to NSMutableData, byte count inconsistent?

Tags: objective-c, byte, nsdata, nsmutabledata

There's this `NSMutableData *dump` to which I must append some `NSData *chunk`.

chunk is 440 bytes and contains the raw bytes read from a file. The file also weights 440 bytes. Good so far.

Now, I must append this:

```
NSMutableData *dump = [NSMutableData data];
[dump appendData:chunk];
```

dump weight 448 bytes. Writing dump to a file causes the file to weight 448 bytes. How can this behavior be explained?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to bindiff the two files?

Comment: Good idea :-) Let's have a look...

Comment: Ah indeed. Content wasn't the same, a file handling layer of this application added encryption. It's using AES256 and thus adds a few bytes to each chunk it scrambles. Thanks for your lead :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category was added to NSData to override the default behavior of `writeToFile:atomically:`

AES256 add a few byte to the chunk it encrypts.